# How to use QML Loader when the loaded component references another internal component

Tags: qt, qml

I have a repo at https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/tree/loader_with_another_component

I am using Loader to load the MyDeeperComponent into main.qml's Column. However, MyDeeperComponent references another internal component called MySquare. When it loads, I get the error `MySquare is not a type` and the program quits. Of course, if I comment out MySquare from MyDeeperComponentForm.ui.qml, everything works and MyDeeperComponent loads successfully.

What needs to be changed so MyDeeperComponent can use MySquare and be dynamically loaded?

The directory structure is:

```
$ tree qml_location/
qml_location/
├── MySquare.qml
├── MySquareForm.ui.qml
├── main.cpp
├── main.qml
├── qml
│   └── more
│       ├── MyDeeperComponent.qml
│       └── MyDeeperComponentForm.ui.qml
├── qml.qrc
├── qml_location.pro
└── qml_location.pro.user
```

[qml_location.pro](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/qml_location.pro)

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/qml

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/qml

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

[qml.qrc](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/qml.qrc)

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>qml/more/MyDeeperComponent.qml</file>
        <file>qml/more/MyDeeperComponentForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file>MySquare.qml</file>
        <file>MySquareForm.ui.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

[main.qml](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/main.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window
{
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true

  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Column
  {
    MySquare {}

    Loader {
        source: "qrc:/qml/more/MyDeeperComponent.qml"
    }
  }
}
```

[main.cpp](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/main.cpp)

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

  engine.addImportPath( "qrc:/qml" );

  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                   &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
      QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
  }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

[MySquare.qml](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/MySquare.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.4

MySquareForm {
}
```

[MySquareForm.ui.qml](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/qml_location/blob/loader_with_another_component/MySquareForm.ui.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
  width: 40
  height: 40

  color: "blue"
}
```

Comment: I really think you should go with `import MyComponents 1.0` as I answered in your previous question ;-) This will allow QmlEngine to solve these kind of dependencies

Comment: I am curious if this can be made to work. Seems like there should be a way. Plus, I want to understand the various solutions to this general problem for reasons explained at https://www.reddit.com/r/QtFramework/comments/mgeuss/what_are_debugging_techniques_to_resolve_xxx_is/

Comment: The other reason why an answer to this question is important is because I would like to be able to dynamically load a set of components. While it may be necessary to include a maintenance task of modifying MyComponents/qmldir every time a new component is added, I prefer to reduce such tasks. I would prefer to just pop a couple of files into the folder and just have stuff work. This works as long as those components do not reference other custom components. Hence, another reason for this question which someone strangely downvoted for an unknown reason.

Comment: Does `import "../../"` in the MyDeeperComponent help? I haven't come across `.ui.qml` files before so sorry if that's too obvious / not working.

Comment: @splaytreez That did work. My impression is that .ui.qml files are a fairly new feature of QML. They allow you to split the implementation of a component between two files. <name>.qml is for the business logic of the component. <name>Form.ui.qml is for the layout of the component. In the <name>Form.ui.qml files, for example, you cannot have any javascript, etc....they are just for general layout.

Comment: another way of doing it is by adding `addImportPath` for every folder in question, possibly through a `QDirIterator(":")`..

Comment: ```addImportPath``` does not appear to work. I wrote ```engine.addImportPath( "qrc:/qml" );```, ```engine.addImportPath( "qrc:/qml/more" );```, and ```engine.addImportPath( "qrc:/" );``` and it was insufficient to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively edit `MyDeeperComponentForm.ui.qml` by changing

```
MySquare {}
```

to

```
Loader {
  source: "../../MySquare.qml"
}
```

or by adding (as already mentioned in the comments)

```
import "../.."
```

Note however, that your use case looks pretty weird from the dependency point of view... I suppose you are already familiar with different import mechanisms in QML but adding the [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html) anyway for reference.